# search data using ajax and django and redirect to related pages

Tags: django, ajax, search

I am building a website and I want to implement searching. I want the user to enter some text and want to show suggestions using ajax. when the user click on specific product or category I want to redirect the user to related page. Here is what I have done so far:

```js
$(function () {
        $("#search").autocomplete({
            source: "{% url 'ajax-search' %}",
            select: function (event, ui) { //item selected
                AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
            },
            minLength: 5,
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="search">
    <label for="search"></label>
    <input type="text" oninput="" style="height: 36px"      class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?"  name="searchtext" id="search">
    <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
     <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
     </button>
</div>
```

```
path('ajax/search', views.autocompleteModel, name='ajax-search'),

def autocompleteModel(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    q = request.GET.get('term', '')
    lookups = Q(name__icontains=q) | Q(category__name__icontains=q)
    products = Product.objects.filter(lookups).distinct()
    results = []
    for product in products:
        place_json = {}
        place_json = product.name
        product_url = 'prodcuts/product/' + str(product.id)
        results.append(place_json)
    data = json.dumps(results)
else:
    data = 'fail'
mimetype = 'application/json'
return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to make urls to work when user select a product from dropdown. I want to redirect user to that specific product page

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript section you have to do something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: "{% url 'ajax-search' %}",
        select: function (event, ui) {
            window.location.href = ui.item.value;
        },
        minLength: 5,
    });
});
```

And Python code part should look like this:

```
results = []
for product in products:
  item = dict(
    label = product.name,
    value = '/products/product/' + str(product.id)
  )
  results.append(item)
data = json.dumps(results)
```

Comment: It worked. when I click on one product I redirects me to that product page which I wanted but on that product page when I search again some other product the URL looks like this "http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/product/products/product/1" and it throws 404 error. why is that ?

Comment: You need to change the URL to absolute (instead of relative) by prepending forward-slash (/) at the start of the URL. e.g. `value = '/products/product/' + str(product.id)`. But, the best way to create URL's is to use Django built-in functions for this, like `value = reverse('client:products', kwargs={'id': product.id})` - you can read more about this here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/